# Newly installed mediawiki 1.28.0 errors: Operation not permitted & not a valid stream resource

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

I was trying to migrate my 1.17.2 MediaWiki installation onto a new hosting site, but due to mysql (vs. mysqli) decprecation, I went ahead installed a fresh copy of MediaWiki 1.28.0 and will attempt to migrate what I need later. However, this didn't install cleanly.

> Warning:
>   rename(/tmp/l10n_cache-en.cdb.tmp.886259483,/tmp/l10n_cache-en.cdb):
>   Operation not permitted in
>   /home2/accountname/public_html/mediawiki-1.28.0/vendor/wikimedia/cdb/src/Writer/PHP.php
>   on line 89
>
> Warning: fclose(): 186 is not a valid stream resource in
>   /home2/accountname/public_html/mediawiki-1.28.0/vendor/wikimedia/cdb/src/Writer/PHP.php
>   on line 236 [WHqpF8C5gMYAATYRG-UAAAJy] 2017-01-14 22:41:28: Fatal
>   exception of type MWException
>
> Warning: fwrite(): 186 is not a valid stream resource in
>   /home2/accountname/public_html/mediawiki-1.28.0/vendor/wikimedia/cdb/src/Writer/PHP.php
>   on line 100
>
> Warning: fclose(): 186 is not a valid stream resource in
>   /home2/accountname/public_html/mediawiki-1.28.0/vendor/wikimedia/cdb/src/Writer/PHP.php
>   on line 236
>
> Warning: unlink(/tmp/l10n_cache-en.cdb.tmp.886259483): No such file or
>   directory in
>   /home2/accountname/public_html/mediawiki-1.28.0/vendor/wikimedia/cdb/src/Writer/PHP.php
>   on line 237
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Cdb\Exception' with message 'Error
>   writing to CDB file "/tmp/l10n_cache-en.cdb.tmp.886259483".' in
>   /home2/accountname/public_html/mediawiki-1.28.0/vendor/wikimedia/cdb/src/Writer/PHP.php:239
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home2/accountname/public_html/mediawiki-1.28.0/vendor/wikimedia/cdb/src/Writer/PHP.php(102):
>   Cdb\Writer\PHP->throwException('Error writing t...') #1
>   /home2/accountname/public_html/mediawiki-1.28.0/vendor/wikimedia/cdb/src/Writer/PHP.php(215):
>   Cdb\Writer\PHP->write('\x00\f\xD1\xB69\xCC\x02\x00') #2
>   /home2/accountname/public_html/mediawiki-1.28.0/vendor/wikimedia/cdb/src/Writer/PHP.php(82):
>   Cdb\Writer\PHP->finish() #3
>   /home2/accountname/public_html/mediawiki-1.28.0/vendor/wikimedia/cdb/src/Writer.php(88):
>   Cdb\Writer\PHP->close() #4 [internal function]:
>   Cdb\Writer->__destruct() #5 {main} thrown in
>   /home2/accountname/public_html/mediawiki-1.28.0/vendor/wikimedia/cdb/src/Writer/PHP.php
>   on line 239

The new host is eHost. I've installed MediaWiki many times over the last decade on different hosts and this is the first time I've had significant issues. It looks like something is trying to write to /tmp? Not cool, but is it configurable?

Comment: While hoping for an answer, I am trying 1.27.1. Of note, the same warning upon installation I got on 1.28.0 install was received. It is: "Warning: Could not find APCu, XCache or WinCache.". This wasn't enough to stop either install. FWIW, 1.27.1 just gave me a database error upon first try, not the other error.

Comment: Rather, 1.27.1 gave me the same errors as 1.28.0 listed above.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I set [this variable](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgTmpDirectory) within my LocalSettings.php to a writable directory:

```
$wgTmpDirectory = "/home2/accountname/public_html/tmp";
```

Further credit to: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T127127